# How would I create a numpy array out of a .mat file?

Tags: numpy, file, matrix, scipy, numpy-ndarray

this is what im currently doing, I don't believe its working as I want it to. though.

[image]

I tried adding it as a Scipy matrix and then converting it to a np array

Comment: You get that error because arr.shape is a tuple; not a method. Read the loadmat docs.  They clearly explain what `data_mat` is, and how to extract variables from it.  Don't blindly wrap everything in `np.array`.  READ THE DOCS

Comment: Show `print(data_mat)`